# Customizing Configurable Map Viewer (CMV) to be available on two languages choosing with button click?

Tags: dojo, configurable-map-viewer, internationalization

I want to make this application available on two languages (MK and EN) depending on whether the user choose (click) [MK] or [EN] button.

If I set variable loc = "MK", default application language will be "MK", but if I click on button [EN] to change the application language, I don't know how to reload dojoConfig.

[image]

Comment: Please always provide code as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by reloading the index.html page on anchor click, adding "lang" parameter in the URL.
I hope this solution will help someone else.

[image]

Comment: Please always provide code as text rather than pictures.